# Is there an elegant way to reorder data frame by rownames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with random row names. And I would like to reorder it by the row names. Say the original dataframe looks like:

```
       value
gene8  0.140533602
gene6 21.129493396
gene7  0.170091711
gene3 28.101415822
gene1  0.005706749
gene2  3.157911375
```

And what I want is:

```
       value
gene1  0.005706749
gene2  3.157911375
gene3 28.101415822
gene6 21.129493396
gene7  0.170091711
gene8  0.140533602
```

After searching for the solution, I've found two ways that can almost solve the issue:

1. Using function `arrange()`. But it can't take row name as the sorting index.
2. Using function `order()` and do it in this way `df <- df[order(row.names(df)), ]`. But what you get is a numeric vector instead of a dataframe. So the row name will be missing.

Solution 1 looks very elegant, but it can't achieve my goal. Solution 2 can be used, but some extra work needs to be added (creating a new dataframe assigning the values and row names). Is there a straight-forway way to do the job?

Comment: In 2. *"But what you get is a numeric vector instead of a dataframe"* this is false.

Comment: See [Filtering single-column data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090896/filtering-single-column-data-frames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works just fine with `arrange()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

d <- read.table(textConnection("
             value
gene8  0.140533602
gene6 21.129493396
gene7  0.170091711
gene3 28.101415822
gene1  0.005706749
gene2  3.157911375")) 


d %>% 
  arrange(row.names(.))
#>              value
#> gene1  0.005706749
#> gene2  3.157911375
#> gene3 28.101415822
#> gene6 21.129493396
#> gene7  0.170091711
#> gene8  0.140533602
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `drop = FALSE` to disable coercion to the lowest possible dimension.

```
df <- df[order(row.names(df)), , drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 0):

since there is one column subsetting returns a numeric vector, this will work;

```
df$dummycol <- rep(1,nrow(df))

df <- df[sort(rownames(df)),]

df$dummycol <- NULL

df
```

**output;**

```
        value
        <dbl>
gene1   0.005706749
gene2   3.157911375
gene3   28.101415822
gene6   21.129493396
gene7   0.170091711
gene8   0.140533602
```